# including $ in search string for get_json_object

Tags: json, hive, hiveql

`$` is used as root object for `get_json_object`. My json string has already `$` in the name of json key, how can I extract it's value? I dont want to use json_tuple.

```
create external table testing_hive (records string);
insert into testing_hive values("{\"$num\":\"hey\"}");

select get_json_object(testing_hive.records, '$.$num') from testing_hive;
```

Comment: What is the reason of not using json_tuple, may I ask?

Comment: basically json is too nested, want to avoid using lateral view everytime. But, ended up using json_tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `"$num"` with something else without `$` in it, for example `"xx_num"`:

```
select get_json_object(regexp_replace(testing_hive.records,'\\"\\$num\\"','\\"xx_num\\"'), '$.xx_num') as num from testing_hive;
```

Result:

```
hey
```

Also you can replace $ for all keys with some other prefix in single regex_replace:

```
regexp_replace(testing_hive.records,'\\"\\$(.*?\\":)','\\"xx_$1')
```

I included `":` in the pattern to make sure it will match keys only, not values. Use `'$1'` as a replacement instead of `'\\"xx_$1'` if you want to remove `$` and leave key without `$` as is.

Hope you got the idea. Modify regex pattern accordingly.